# Watson Text to Speechで日本語をPOSTで送る方法を教えて下さい

Tags: bluemix

文字コード問題の可能性があるので、まず事前情報として私の使用環境を書きます。
OS=Windows7 64bit
コンソール=コマンドプロンプト
使用しているcurlコマンド=Gitに同梱されていた物です。

```
curl -V
curl 7.30.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.30.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.7
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI libz
```

ここからが質問です。
**どうすればPOSTで日本語を送れるでしょうか？**
「こんにちは、ワトソン博士」と言う文字をPOSTで送りたいのですが、下記コマンドでは無音ファイル(ja_post.ogg)ができてしまいます。

```
curl -X POST -u "{userid}:{pasword}" -o "ja_post.ogg" -H "content-type:application/json" -d "{\"text\":\"こんにちは、ワトソン博士\"}" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=ja-JP_EmiVoice"
```

**11/26結論追記
・Windowsのコマンドプロンプトでは文字コードがcp932のためNG！
・BOM無しUTF-8でファイルを作り、`--data-binary @ファイル名`で送ればOK！
**

参考として以下は成功する例です。
英文のHelloを送ると、正常(?)に「えいちえるえるおー」と言う音声ファイルができます。

```
curl -X POST -u "{userid}:{pasword}" -o "ja_post.ogg" -H "content-type:application/json" -d "{\"text\":\"Hello\"}" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=ja-JP_EmiVoice"
```

これと同様にjsonデータを`-d "{\"text\":\"%E3%81... \"}"`と言うエンコードした文字に変えると、「ぱーせんといーさんぱーせんとはちいち...」と言うファイルが出来てしまいます。

POSTではなく、GETでエンコード文字を送ると正しく「こんにちは わとそんはくし」と言うファイルができます。

```
curl -u "{userid}:{pasword}" -o "ja_get.ogg" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=ja-JP_EmiVoice&text=%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81%E3%83%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%BD%E3%83%B3%E5%8D%9A%E5%A3%AB%22"
```

これはcurlの使い方が悪いのか、操作している環境が悪いのか、watsonサービス側の問題なのか。。。
ご教授願します。

**追記** (エラーになるとの事なので コメントの内容を代わりに追記します)

```
C:\>chcp 現在のコード ページ: 932
C:\>chcp Active code page: 65001
```

コードページ65001(UTF-8)を試してみた理由は他のwatsonサービスでファイルの文字コードはUTF-8と言う記述があったので試してみました。

curlのオプションについは下記パターンを試しました。○の２つが上手く行った物です。ただし試したのはcp932状態だったかも・・・です。

```
+ ×：`-d "{\"text\":\"こんにちは、ワトソン博士\"}"`
+ ×：`--data-urlencode "{\"text\":\"こんにちは、ワトソン博士\"}"`
+ ×：`--data-binary "{\"text\":\"こんにちは、ワトソン博士\"}"`
+ ○：`-d "{\"text\":\"HelloWorld\"}"`
+ ○：`--data-binary "{\"text\":\"HelloWorld\"}"`
+ ×→◎：`--data-binary @ja_post.json`　**※これで上手く行きました！！**
+ ×：`-d @ja_post.json`
+ ×：`-d =@ja_post.json`
```

※ja_post.jsonファイルの中身はUTF-8で{"text":"HelloWorld"}です

### ↑BOM付きUTF-8になってました！ BOM無しUTF-8で正常終了しました♪

11/25追記 Yamazaki
--data-urlencodeの部分を修正しました。改めて試しましたがやはりダメでした。
ちなみにcp932での実行時画面は下記の通りで、見にくいですが、Received(太字)のサイズが明らかに小さくなっています。

```
curl -X POST -u "{userid}:{pasword}" -o "ja_post.ogg" -H "content-type:application/json" -d "{\"text\":\"Hello
\"}" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=ja-JP_EmiVoice"
  % Total    % **Received** % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 **18060**    0 18044  100    16   7512      6  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  7512

curl -X POST -u "{userid}:{pasword}" -o "ja_post.ogg" -H "content-type:application/json" --data-urlencode "{\"
text\":\"こんにちは、ワトソン博士\"}" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=ja-JP_EmiVoice"
  % Total    % **Received** % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   **196**    0   105  100    91     69     60  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    70
```

またコマンドプロンプトの文字コードを65001にすると漢字が入力できず、コピペの貼り付けも文字化けて"□□□□"的な表記になり、上手く行きません。
やはりwindowsだと何かとやりにくいですね・・・。

---

11/25 追記 Yamazaki
上記で無音ja_post.oggをテキストエディタで開くと、中身はなんとエラー応答のjsonファイルになってました！ 
これで少なくともwatsonサービスとして正当に(?)エラーを応答している事が分かりました。一歩前身です♪

```
{
   "code_description": "Bad Request", 
   "code": 400, 
   "error": "No JSON object could be decoded"
}
```

でもこのエラーだとUTF-8のjsonが送られてないからエラーなのか、watson側が２バイト文字のjsonをパースできずにエラーなのかが分かりませんね・・・。
うむむ、試しにサーバー側にRESTでjson受け取るアプリ作ってcurlから投げて中身確かめてみるしか無いかなぁ・・・

---

11/26 追記 Yamazaki
`-d "{\"text\":\"１\"}"`　（全角の１）にした所、エラー応答が下記に変わりました。

```
{
   "code_description": "Bad Request",
   "code": 400,
   "error": "UnicodeDecodeError: request body does not contain legal UTF-8. 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 9: invalid start byte"
}
```

これはと思い、UTF-8でテキストファイルを作りなおして
`--data-binary @ja_post.json` とした所「こんにちは わとそんはくし」と喋りました！！
上記で一度試しているのですがそのファイルがNGだった原因は使ったエディタの関係でBOM付きUTF-8になっていたためでした。。。 orz

これにて完全解決です！ありがうございました！！
※先頭に結論を追記しました。

Comment: Watsonについて知見はないので 参考までにコメントします。まず `文字コード問題の可能性があるので` とのことですがコレについてなにか調べられていたら質問に追記してみてください。コマンドプロンプトだと cp932 だと思いますので UTF-8 に変えてみるとか試せますか？あとは `-d` を別のオプションに変えると変化ないでしょうか。POSTデータのオプションは他に --data-ascii --data-binary --data-urlencode があります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
コマンドプロンプトでは、下記２種類で動作確認しましたが、いずれも同様の結果となっております。
`C:\>chcp
現在のコード ページ: 932`
`C:\>chcp
Active code page: 65001`
コードページ65001(UTF-8)を試してみた理由は他のwatsonサービスでファイルの文字コードはUTF-8と言う記述があったので試してみました。

curlのオプションについは下記パターンを試しました。○の２つが上手く行った物です。ただし試したのはcp932状態だったかも・・・です。
×：-d "{\"text\":\"こんにちは、ワトソン博士\"}"
×：-data-urlencode "{\"text\":\"こんにちは、ワトソン博士\"}"
×：--data-binary "{\"text\":\"こんにちは、ワトソン博士\"}"
○：-d "{\"text\":\"HelloWorld\"}"
○：--data-binary "{\"text\":\"HelloWorld\"}"
×：--data-binary @ja_post.json　
×：-d @ja_post.json　
×：-d =@ja_post.json　
　※ja_post.jsonファイルの中身はUTF-8で{"text":"HelloWorld"}です

Comment: 操作に不慣れでスイマセン。コメントに記述すると改行されないのですね。。。　質問に追記するために編集を押し、内容を追記したうえで保存しようとすると「編集内容の送信中にエラーが発生しました。」というエラーで保存する事ができません。

Comment: たぶん入力ミスだとは思いますが念のため。`-data-urlencode` は ハイフンが一つ足りませんが `--data-urlencode` で試されましたか？

Comment: コメントと情報の追記ありがとうございます。`--data-urlencode`で改めて試して見ましたがダメでした。情報として正常に行くHelloとの結果出力差異を追記してみました。

Comment: あまり役に立てませんがせっかくなので思いついたことをコメントします…。出来上がった無音ファイルは実はHTTPメッセージが書かれたHTMLだということはありませんか？

Comment: take88さん、ありがとうございます！結果ファイルの中身を見てみるって事が発想からすっかり漏れていました。本文に追記した通りjson形式でエラー応答になってました。問題は解決してませんが、正しくエラー扱いされてる事が分かって一歩前進です♪

Comment: 仮にcp932で送られてるとすると「ソ」は 0x5c を含むのでエラーになりそうな気がしますね。違う文字列でもエラーになりますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます解決しました！質問に追記しましたが、全角１を送るとUTF-8じゃないと怒られ、改めてUTF-8でファイルを作って送ると上手く行きました！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメントをヒントに無事解決しました。
上手く行かない理由はWindowsのコマンドプロンプトを使用したため。コマンドプロンプト上で入力した文字はcp932で送られる。（UTF-8じゃないのでNGとなる）

コマンドプロンプトで試す場合は、別途BOM無しUTF-8でテキストファイルを作り、そのファイルを`--data-binary @ファイル名`で送ればOK！

コマンド全体としては下記の通り。(BOM無しUTF-8でinputText.jsonファイルを指定）
    `curl -X POST -u "{userid}:{pasword}" -o "ja_post.ogg" -H "content-type:application/json" --data-binary @inputText.json "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=ja-JP_EmiVoice"`